# Subtract and add a quantity in one line of code in R?

Tags: r

Maybe this is too simple of a question, but I was wondering if it might be possible to have `qnorm(.975)*1/sqrt(34 - 3))` be subtracted from and added to  `tanh(atanh(.5)` ***without*** writing `-` and `+` in two separate lines of code (but instead in one line of code)?

**Here is the R code:**

```
tanh(atanh(.5)  -  qnorm(.975)*1/sqrt(34 - 3))
tanh(atanh(.5)  +  qnorm(.975)*1/sqrt(34 - 3))
```

Comment: Tip: R is vectorized. `tanh(atanh(.5)  + c(-1, 1)*qnorm(.975)*1/sqrt(34 - 3))`. (The vector `c(-1, 1)` multiplies `qnorm`.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Looks like it would make an excellent answer

Comment: Just curious: `sqrt(34 - 3)` can be `sqrt(31)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon a bit thinking, the statistical answer is the following:

```
tanh(atanh(.5) + qnorm(c(.025, .975))*1/sqrt(34 - 3))
#[1] 0.1947659 0.7169429
```

Answer (score 2):

R is vectorized. So, take advantage of it.

```
tanh(atanh(.5) + c(-1, 1)*qnorm(.975)*1/sqrt(34 - 3))
#[1] 0.1947659 0.7169429
```

The vector `c(-1, 1)` multiplies the recycled value of `qnorm` giving a vector of length 2, as required.